# Can tinyXML-1 open files on Android?

Tags: android, tinyxml

TinyXML-1 can't open file. File exist on that path, but xmlDoc.ErrorDesc() writes Failed to open file. Can tinyXML1 open files on android or I must use Tinyxml2?

Comment: bool StateParser::parseState(const char *stateFile, std::string stateID, std::vector<GameObject *> *pObjects, std::vector<std::string> *pTextureIDs)
{
    // create the XML document
    TiXmlDocument xmlDoc;

    // load the state file
    if(!xmlDoc.LoadFile(stateFile))
    {

        std::cerr << xmlDoc.ErrorDesc() << "\n";

        return false;
    }

Answer (score 1):

What is the exact error on your logcat?

It can be just that you didn't put the required permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

In your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Logcat doesn't show any errors. I have that permision in AnroidManifest.xml, but xmlDoc.LoadFile(File) returns NULL and file dosen't load.

Comment: Put the code where you create the File variable (the one inside xmlDoc.Loadfile(>File<)).